# How can I use properties of external library object that returned from a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, oop, casting, createjs

I'm using [createjs](http://www.createjs.com/) to make html5 game bu there is a problem in this part of code:

```
function createGameObj(){
   var text = new createjs.Text("Some Text","16px Arial","white");
   var container = new createjs.Container();
   container.addChild(text);
   return container;
}
```

I have a function like above. When I call this and get an object that returned from it, I cant use its properties.

```
function prepareGameStage(){
   var obj = createGameObj(); //It should be typeof createjs.Container when we do typecasting which we get used to see at oop
   obj.x = canvas.width/2; //this doesnt make any errors but also doesnt work. So I cant access "x" property of "createjs.Container" type object.
   stage.addChild(obj); //error occurs here because of undefined type of obj. 
}
```

I tried to cast obj like this:

```
obj = Object.create(createjs.Container,createGameObj());
```

But it didn' work.

Do you guys have any solutions for that?

Comment: Your code should work, there must be something else wrong with it. Don't try to "cast" anything, and certainly not using `Object.create`.

Comment: What do `console.log(container)` and `console.log(obj)` give?

Comment: container is typeof Object, obj is undefined.

Comment: sorry my bad. container is not an Object. it gives "[Container (name=null)]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. Just like [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) said I made a mistake on another statement.My createGameObj was like :

```
function createGameObj(){
   var text = new createjs.Text("Some Text","16px Arial","white");
   var container = new createjs.Container();
   container.addChild(text);
   function(event){
      //do some here
      return container;
   }
}
```

and it returned the container object to createGameObj function.And Because of createGameObj function haven't return statement it returned 'undefined' as default. I realised it late :).Deleted nested function and solved.